# Meteor - checkbox is maintaining old value

Tags: meteor, checkbox, underscore.js, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I am new to Meteor :)

I have a template helper:

```
    userRoleMap: function() {
        var u = getUser();
        if (u) {
            var lstRoles = Meteor.roles.find({}).fetch();
            var userRoles = u.roles ? u.roles : [];

            _.map(lstRoles, function(r) {
                _.extend(r, {
                    userMapped: _.contains(userRoles, r.name)
                });
                return r;
            });

            return lstRoles;
        }

        return [];
   }
```

I am using this helper in my template as:

```
{{#each userRoleMap}}
   <div class="checkbox">
     <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chkUserRole" value="{{name}}" checked="{{userMapped}}"> {{name}}
     </label>
   </div>
{{/each}}
```

I am showing the above html/template in a bootstrap-modal. I am showing this modal on click of a button (and setting user-id in a Session which I am using when calling getUser() function).

The issue is the checkbox check state is not changing based on value of "userMapped". It is getting set correctly first time, but not afterwards. The helper `userRoleMap` is getting called every-time I open modal, but the checkboxes are having same checked state which they had when it was opened previously (manual checks/unchecks are getting maintained).

The return value of helper method is working as expected (verified by logging it on console).

Anything I am missing here ? Something to do with _.extend() ?

Answer (score 0):

The Meteor way to do this is to either return checked as an element attribute or not:

```
Template.registerHelper( 'checked', ( a, b ) => {
  return a === b ? 'checked' : '';
});

{{#each userRoleMap}}
   <div class="checkbox">
     <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="chkUserRole" value="{{name}}" {{checked userMapped true}}> {{name}}
     </label>
   </div>
{{/each}}
```